# Using Entity Framework for 2 databases in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have no idea how to use EF to connect to 2 databases separately, I just use 1 database only before.

I have to model `ActivityLog` and `RegistrationData`.

Here are the connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DevSaveLog" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=BIFASTAPI_Log;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DevSaveRegis" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=BIFASTAPI_Reg;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is my existing DContext (using an old connection string)

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ActivityLog> ActivityLogs { get; set; } //<<< I want this in DevSaveLog
    public DbSet<RegistrationData> RegistrationDatas { get; set; } //<< I want this in DevSaveRegis
}
```

How can I apply those? Thanks sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: Just go ahead and use two DbContexts (with different class names).

Answer (score 1):

As Ben already pointed out in the comments, you will need two seperate DbContext Classes. Each will use its own connection string in order to connect to its specific database. You might inject your specific connection string using Dependency Injection.

```csharp
public class LogContext : DbContext
{
    private IConfiguration config { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ActivityLog> ActivityLogs { get; set; }

    public LogContext(IConfiguration config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        // use configuration string called "DevSaveLog"
    }
}

public class RegistrationContext : DbContext
{
    private IConfiguration config { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RegistrationData> RegistrationDatas { get; set; }

    public RegistrationContext(IConfiguration config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        // use configuration string called "DevSaveRegis"
    }
}
```

You then want to inject both of these Context into the class, you want to use them with.

Example:

```csharp
public class Example
{
    private LogContext logContext {get;set;}
    private RegistrationContext registrationContext {get;set;}
    public Example(LogContext log, RegistrationContext registration)
    {
        this.logContext = log;
        this.registrationContext = registration;
    }

    public void ExampleMethod()
    {
        var logs = logContext.ActivitryLogs;
        var registrations = registrationContext.RegistrationDatas;
    }
}
```